# I'm running testng from command line but no tests get executed

Tags: java, selenium, testng

If I run my testng.xml from Eclipse IDE, everything works well; but if aI try to run them from command line then i see following[image]

Folder structure:
[image]

My Class is following, whose test are run fine when I run from eclipse IDE:

```
package package1;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Example1 {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void launchBrowser() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Eclipse\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void verifygoogleTitle() {
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        Assert.assertEquals("Google", driver.getTitle());
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void verifyyahooTitle() {
        driver.get("https://in.yahoo.com");
        Assert.assertEquals("Yahoo", driver.getTitle());
    }

    @Test(priority = 3)
    public void verifybankofindiaTitle() {
        driver.get("http://www.bankofindia.co.in/english/home.aspx");
        Assert.assertEquals("Bank Of India - Home", driver.getTitle());
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void closeBrowser() {
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

My testng.xml is following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="package1.Example1"/>

    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**[UPDATE] Extended Logs :**

[image]

Comment: please post test code, location ...

Comment: Location of what?

Comment: As I remember test method must have `test` prefix. For example change `verifygoogleTitle` to `testVerifygoogleTitle`. And run again

Comment: Okay I'll Try that

Comment: Nope, nothing happened, could it be that I'm running it as maven project for managing dependencies?

Comment: Did you try to run it through Eclipse?

Comment: It works well via Eclipse

Comment: So the problem is not unit test but `testing.xml`

Comment: How could that be when it works fine on Eclipse?

Comment: Google it, I think you have enough posts how to run unit testing from CLI

Comment: Well; I've checked a few

Comment: Could you share the output with the extended log? `java org.testng.TestNG -log 10 testng.xml`?

Comment: @juherr : I've updated my question w/ extended logs.

Comment: Really strange. TestNG found the class but it doesn't see the annotation. Could put the latest TestNG version (6.11) in the lib directory, remove previous versions and try again?

Comment: This time I got the same result for TestNG and it didn't produce any extended report

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. testng.xml was running fine if I run it from Eclipse but when I run the same from command prompt ; it gave the result as 0 tests run, there was no errors.

My issue was in my classpath setting. I had kept all my TestNG jar files in a separate folder (to organize better) in eclipse project's lib directory while the rest of my jar files were directly in the lib directory. When I added the lib as well to my classpath it worked fine.

set classpath = D:\workspace\SeleniumTrials\bin;D:\workspace\SeleniumTrials\lib\TestNG*;D:\workspace\SeleniumTrials\lib* java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Answer (score 0):

Let me address your question here with a few points:

1. If at all we are using maven, there is no need to install (add TestNG libraries) TestNG seperately (manually) either by `Install New Software`or `Eclipse Market Place`. Instead we can simply specify the TestNG dependency in the `pom.xml` as follows:

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>6.8</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Advantages: `maven-surefire-plugin` does all the downloading & configuration for us.

2. Now, we have got 4 optional ways to execute the Testcase as follows:

A. `Run As TestNG Test` (Eclipse, through .java file)

B. `Run As TestNG Suite` (Eclipse, through testng.xml)

C. `Run As maven test` (Eclipse, through pom.xml)

D. Command-line option.

For command line execution: 
a. We have to specify in `pom.xml` where to find the `testng.xml`. For example:

```html
<suiteXmlFiles>
<suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
```

To achieve this,

b. We have to move the `testng.xml` to `src/main/resources`

c. Through command-line change directory to project folder.

d. Flush out previous dependencies.

e. Install the necessary dependencies.

f. Install build & execute testcase.

Let me know if this answers your question.